# Expression inside a list in Racket

Tags: list, racket

If I have a list like this `(define lst '((,(car '(1 2)) (1 2)) (,(car '(3 4)) (3 4))) )` and I try to 'evaluate' the expression (i.e. take as result `'((1 (1 2)) (3 (3 4)))`) I obtain the same list that I have.

I know that if I use `(quoasiquote ((,(car '(1 2)) (1 2)) (,(car '(3 4)) (3 4)))` I obtain what I'm looking for, but the problem is in an execution with an iterative method, where (I think) I'm not capable of take only the values, without being a list. (i.e. take only the second part of the `quoasiquote` expression).

For example, if I use `for/list` and I do `(list-ref lst 0)`, I obtain `'(,(car '(1 2)) (1 2))`, when I want `(,(car '(1 2)) (1 2))` for use it in `quoasiquote` function.

How can I obtain the expression inside a list and evaluate it?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please write the `for/list` loop you intend to create, indicating the result you expect and the result you're currently obtaining

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I hope now It's better explained!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you quote data it's like single quotes in some popular Algol dialects like perl. eg `print '$_';` actually prints $_ and not the value the variable $_ represents. If you would have used double quotes the variables in the string is expanded to it's value.

In Scheme we have `(quote x)` which is `'x`. Nothing in it will ever going to become evaluated since it's quoted with `'`. If it were `` `x ``, which is the same as `(quasiquote x)` then Scheme looks for `,expression` (same as `(unquote expression)` ) and `,@expression` (same as `(unquote-splicing expression)` ). These quote forms are **NOT** procedures but macros. It transforms your static code to different static code.

So `` (begin (define test 10) `((1 2) (3 ,(+ test 4)))) ; ==> ((1 2) (3 14)) ``

What Scheme really does is transform it into `(list '(1 2) (list 3 (+ test 4)))`, while if it was `` `((3 ,(+ test 4)) (1 2)) `` it turns into `(cons (list 3 (+ test 4)) '((1 2)))` since the tail can be a constant but the head cannot if it needs to have a evaluated tail.

I get the impression from you question that you think you can store the text and expand them later like `` (let ((x '((1 2) (3 ,(+ test 4))))) `x) `` but that will not work since  `quasiquote` is a macro and thus it will evaluate to x. and `` (let ((x '((1 2) (3 ,(+ test 4))))) `,x) `` would evaluate to `((1 2) (3 ,(+ test 4)))`.

Comment: I have to say that all you wrote here is in the manual of Racket, and I read it before post the question. After this, I have to say, sincerely, that your explanation is REALLY good. Better than the manual. And you're right :) . I cannot, so I'm going to adapt it to the @uselpa answer. Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident that we have an [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here because what you describe is pretty unusual. Also, the only solution I imagine here is using `eval`, which again shows that you're probably heading into the wrong direction.

But here's a little attempt at what I *believe* you want:

```scm
(define lst '((list (car '(1 2)) '(1 2))
              (list (car '(3 4)) '(3 4))))

(define-namespace-anchor nsa)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace nsa))

(for/list ((i lst)) 
  (define e (eval i ns))
  (printf "evaluating ~a    to    ~a\n" i e)
  e)
```

which will print

```scm
evaluating (list (car '(1 2)) '(1 2))    to    (1 (1 2))
evaluating (list (car '(3 4)) '(3 4))    to    (3 (3 4))
```

and evaluate to

```scm
'((1 (1 2)) (3 (3 4)))
```

Comment: Your answer works if I change `,` for `list`, what it's the same. But with `,` doesn't work, so, I'm gonna adapt my code to this. Thank you.